# Feynman rule: proton-proton-photon versus electron-electron-photon QED vertex

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

If the Feynman rule for the vertex is written as $$-ieQ\gamma^\mu$$ ($e>0$, charge of positron, $Q$ is the charge of the interacting particle in units of $e$), the electron-electron-photon QED interaction vertex will carry a minus sign relative to proton-proton-photon QED vertex because for proton $Q=+1$ and electron, $Q=-1$. If this is true, I'm confused about a electron-positron-photon vertex. What would be it's sign, relative to the above two vertices?

Comment: There is no electron-positron-photon vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fermionic field operator $\psi(x)$ describes particles $f$ (with charge $q_f$) as well as antiparticles $\bar{f}$ (with charge $-q_f$). The Feynman rule derived from  $$\mathcal{L}_{\rm int}=-q_f\bar{\psi}(x) \gamma^\mu \psi(x)A_\mu(x)$$ is *always* given by $$-iq_f \gamma^\mu$$ independently of the possible interpretations of the interaction vertex (being part of a Feynman diagram) as $$f\to f \gamma, \quad\gamma f \to f, \quad \bar{f} \to \bar{f} \gamma, \quad \gamma \bar{f} \to \bar{f}, \quad \gamma \to f \bar{f}, \quad f \bar{f}\to \gamma.$$